# How to create same text structure every time?

Tags: environments

My document contains 'blocks of text' with the same structure. They always have a title (which is always a date), a *review* part and a *to do* part. This is what the code looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\newenvironment{review}
    {\textbf{Review:} \begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}
\newenvironment{todo}
    {\textbf{To do:} \begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\section*{30th November 2013}
\begin{enumerate}[1)]
    \item blabla
\end{enumerate}

\begin{review}
    \item blabla
\end{review}

\begin{todo}
    \item blabla
\end{todo}
\end{document}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to omit the need to type this structure every time and create a command or environment called *Article* in order to save time and organize my document a little bit better. How can I do this?

Comment: You could create a two-part environment, with a `\todo` macro splitting it in the middle. One question: where is the title in your example?

Comment: @Jubobs: The title is the `\section*` part. I don't know whether this is a good way to define a title, but it works for now. Anyway, the title is always a date.

Comment: @Jubobs: Of course I had the intention to mark an answer as the solution, but I was really busy today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea: a three-part environment called `Article`, whose only (mandatory) argument is the date (specified as `{<day>}{<month>}{<year>}`).

To start the *Review* part, simply use my `\review` macro. To start the *To do* part, simply use my `\todo` macro. It may be wise to rename those macros to avoid clashes with existing macros; for instance, I know that the `todonotes` package defines a macro called  `\todo`.

For more maintainability, you may also want to use a package for typesetting dates, such as Nicola Talbot's `datetime`, which I used in my example. By doing so, you won't need to hardcode the date (as `30th November 2013` in your example) and you will be able to change the way it should be typeset at any stage.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[long,nodayofweek]{datetime}


\newenvironment{Article}[1]
{%
    \newcommand\review
    {%
        \end{enumerate}
        \textbf{Review:}
        \begin{itemize}
    }
    \newcommand\todo
    {%
        \end{itemize}
        \textbf{To do:}
        \begin{itemize}
    }
    \section*{\formatdate#1}
    \begin{enumerate}[1)]   
}{%
    \end{itemize}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{Article}{{30}{11}{2013}}
        \item foo
        \item bar
    \review
        \item foo
        \item bar
    \todo
        \item foo
        \item bar
\end{Article}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once again this is a bit more than what you are asking for, but this is an ideal situation where using keys can stream-line things very nicely (after an initial overhead of constructing them).

I take a four pronged approach here.

1. I define the keys I will use.
2. I define a macro for the user interface.  In this case `\myarticle` that takes one argument for the key-value pairs.  This macro then calls another macro for handling the formatting.
3. I define an internal macro `\my@article` that determines what code to execute.  This is a bit of a middleman, but can be very nice for quickly reformatting, changing the order of presentation, or just debugging.
4. For each aspect of the final *environment* I define a macro to handle the formatting.  Each of these macros follows the naming convention `\jeroen@build@...`.  There's one defined for the **date**, another for **review**, and a third for **to do**. These are the macros that you would redefine if you want to change the presentation of the content.

For the keys, I illustrate three different approaches:

- Use of `.initial` to use `pgfkeys` internal mechanism for storing and recalling a key value.
- Use of `.store in` to store the value of the key in a user defined macro.
- Use of `.code` to execute some code when a particular key is called.

I feel `.code` is the most interesting of these in the current context because, in the following MWE, it will allow the user to opt out of using a **review** list.  Also, for **front matter** I do something similar:  the key value is passed as for the other keys--as though it were a list--but its final formatting is just as a normal paragraph.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%-------------------------------------------
%% packages you need for this to work        
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgffor}
%%-------------------------------------------
%% package OP requested                      
\usepackage{enumitem}           
%%-------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
%%-------------------------------------------
%% These next two macros are not entirely    
%% necessary.  I put them here to illustrate 
%% further possibilities about how `pgfkeys` 
%% can manage keys.                          
\def\jeroen@review@items{}
\def\jeroen@to@do@items{}
\newif\ifjeroen@review@
\newif\ifjeroen@front@matter@
%% define the keys                           
\pgfkeys{/jeroen/article/.cd,
  date/.initial=,
  front matter/.code=\jeroen@front@matter@code{#1},
  review items/.code=\jeroen@review@code{#1},
  to do items/.store in=\jeroen@to@do@items,
}
%% define the macro for user interface       
\newcommand\myarticle[1]{%%
  \bgroup  
  \pgfkeys{/jeroen/article/.cd,#1}%%
  \build@my@article
  \egroup
}
\def\jeroen@front@matter@code#1{%%
  \jeroen@front@matter@true
  \def\jeroen@front@matter@content{#1}}
\def\jeroen@review@code#1{%%
  \jeroen@review@true
  \def\jeroen@review@items{#1}}

%% an internal macro for initially handling  
%% and formatting the content.               
\def\build@my@article{%%
  \jeroen@build@date
  \jeroen@build@front@matter
  \jeroen@build@review
  \jeroen@build@to@do
}
%% macro for formatting the "date"                     
%% If you want to change how the "date" is presented   
%% this is the code you should tweak.                  
\def\jeroen@build@date{%%
  \section*{\pgfkeysvalueof{/jeroen/article/date}}}
%% macro for formatting the "front matter"             
%% If you want to change how the "front matter" is     
%% presented this is the code you should tweak.        
\def\jeroen@build@front@matter{%%
  \ifjeroen@front@matter@
    \foreach \mystuff in \jeroen@front@matter@content
    {\mystuff\space}%%
    \vspace{2ex}\par
  \fi
}
%% macro for working with the list of "review" items   
%% This is the code you should tweak to change how     
%% the "review" is formatted.                          
\def\jeroen@build@review{%%
  \ifjeroen@review@
    \noindent
    \textbf{Review:}
    \begin{enumerate}%%
    \foreach \reviewitem in \jeroen@review@items
    {%%
      \item \reviewitem 
     }%%
    \end{enumerate}
  \fi
}
%% macro for working iwth the list of "to do" items    
%% This is the code you should tweak to change how     
%% the "to do" is formatted.                           
\def\jeroen@build@to@do{%%
  \noindent
  \textbf{To do:}
  \begin{itemize}
  \foreach \todoitem in \jeroen@to@do@items
  {%%
    \item \todoitem
  }%%
  \end{itemize}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myarticle{
  date={November 29, 2013},
  review items={
    {turkey},
    {stuffing},
    {yams}
    },
  to do items={
    {apples},
    {pears},
    {peaches},
    {ice cream}}
}

\myarticle{
  date={November 30, 2013},
  front matter={
    {The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.},
    {Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.}},
  to do items={
    {carrots},
    {celery},
    {parsnips},
    {ice cream!!}}
}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

I should note a couple things:

- The brackets in `date={November 30, 2013}` are necessary to prevent `pgfkeys` from thinking the *comma* in the date is the *separator* for the keys.
- The other keys should be formatted as: `{  {item 1} , {item 2} , {item 3} , ...}`

Granted, this is a lot of initial work to do.  But in the end it provides with a great deal of latitude for how you finally format the content.

Answer (score 0):

A recommended solution only for best practitioners.

### Create a package

As you want to reuse the environments as well as the items in many projects, the best solution is to put all of them in a single package. Save the package in a directory accessible to LaTeX (it will be explained later if you don't know how).

In the following example, I chose `mytodolist.sty` as the name for the package. You can change it if you want to.

```
% mytodolist.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mytodolist}[2013/12/01 v0.01 LaTeX package for my consistent todo list]

\RequirePackage{enumerate}

\newenvironment{review}
    {\textbf{Review:} \begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}
\newenvironment{todo}
    {\textbf{To do:} \begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\Section}[1][\today]{\section*{#1}}

% items that will be reused many times
\newcommand{\foo}{\item foo}
%\newcommand{\bar}{\item bar} % it cannot be made as \bar is already defined!
\newcommand{\baz}{\item baz}

\endinput
```

If you have new items to add, just edit this package. Use `\newcommand` rather than `\def` to make sure that the existing macros don't get redefined.

### Use the package

Now you can use the package as follows.

```
% main.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{mytodolist}

\begin{document}
\Section
\begin{review}
\foo
%\bar
\baz
\end{review}

\begin{todo}
\foo
%\bar
\baz
\end{todo}

\Section[Dec 25, 2013]
\begin{review}
\foo
%\bar
\baz
\end{review}

\begin{todo}
\foo
%\bar
\baz
\end{todo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Simulation 2 in 1

The following code snippet can be used to simulate the creation of the package on the fly and use it. You should not do it for your production scenario.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mytodolist.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mytodolist}[2013/12/01 v0.01 LaTeX package for my consistent todo list]

\RequirePackage{enumerate}

\newenvironment{review}
    {\textbf{Review:} \begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}
\newenvironment{todo}
    {\textbf{To do:} \begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\Section}[1][\today]{\section*{#1}}

% items that will be reused many times
\newcommand{\foo}{\item foo}
%\newcommand{\bar}{\item bar} % it cannot be made as \bar is already defined!
\newcommand{\baz}{\item baz}

\endinput
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{mytodolist}

\begin{document}
\Section
\begin{review}
\foo
%\bar
\baz
\end{review}

\begin{todo}
\foo
%\bar
\baz
\end{todo}

\Section[Dec 25, 2013]
\begin{review}
\foo
%\bar
\baz
\end{review}

\begin{todo}
\foo
%\bar
\baz
\end{todo}
\end{document}
```